# Failed to instantiate module, AngularJS + NodeWebkit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-webkit

I try to make a stand-alone webapp by using Node-Webkit and AngularJS.

I following the AngularJS.org tutorial but i encounter an error when i try to create the angular module.

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hecktelionApp due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'hecktelionApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
root-app-folder
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── js\
│   └── app.js
└── node_modules\
    └── angular\
```

And here are my files

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="hecktelionApp">
    <head>
        <title>Hecktelion : Legacy</title>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world !</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

global.document = window.document;

var angular = require('angular');
var hecktelionApp = angular.module('hecktelionApp', []);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Hecktelion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "author": "Toxicat <marc.guilmard@gmail.com>",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 1280,
    "height": 1024
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.14"
  }
}
```

Which i made wrong ?

Comment: are you sure that the `require` works? are you using browserify for that?

Comment: I confess, I don't know what "browserify" is. I'll look at.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis : browserify make it work but i really would know why and how

Comment: @AvraamMavridis He shouldn't need browserify if he's using node-webkit(NW.js) since you can `require` straight from the DOM.

Comment: @BenFortune yap true, but in the build process their should be something to convert require to "client" side javascript. Right? I am not sure what node-webkit use for that.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis No. [NW.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) builds node.js straight into chromium which as I said before allows you to require modules straight from the DOM.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a Plunk?

Comment: @User970008 : Plunk ?

Comment: @BenFortune : My bad. My version of node-webkit was completely outdated. Thanks to your NW.js link, i update nw.exe and now it's works. Thanks.

Comment: @PanzerKadaver I'm going to add an answer for another fix.

Comment: A plunk is a code editor on Plunker like a fiddle on JSFiddle. Plunker is good for testing Angular because you can have complex file structures and external files. You can do the same thing in a fiddle, but the way the files are listed seem to make it easier for working on Angular. Here is an Angular example: http://plnkr.co/edit/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `window` isn't being defined properly with the way angular is required.

You can wrap your code inside an anonymous function and inject `window` into it.

```
(function() {
    var angular = require('angular');
    var hecktelionApp = angular.module('hecktelionApp', []);
}).bind(window);
```

Comment: Works with old nw.exe (11.2 win64) and the new nw.exe (12.0 alpha 3 win64)